# GFCI trips after adding new circuit to it

Tags: gfci

Preface: I am a complete newbie when it comes to electrical circuits. I usually have electricians do all the work in our house.

An electrician installed a circuit in our backyard with 8 outlets on it. The circuit was controlled by one GFCI.

Everything worked fine, as expected.

A couple of years later, another electrician added another circuit with 2 outlets and an air conditioner compressor to the same GFCI.

Now the GFCI trips every few minutes.

Obviously adding the new circuit has something to do with the GFCI tripping every few minutes. But beyond that I don't know why this is happening and how it could be fixed. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: This started happening how soon after the second electrician's visit? First thought would be to call that electrician back to fix whatever problem they created.

Comment: When you say "*The circuit was controlled by one GFCI.*", do you mean a *ground-fault circuit interrupter* breaker, receptacle,  or a stand alone device?  What size breaker is protecting this circuit? When you say "*air conditioner compressor*", do you mean a large condensing unit for a whole house A/C system?

Answer (score -1):

If you have too many receptacles on a 15 amp circuit this would be the issue as an AC unit will draw some current

Comment: Are you saying that the breaker is tripping because the total current draw is over the maximum allowed by the breaker, rather than because of ground leakage?